# How can I deny an application's request for administrator priviliges?

Tags: macos, permission

I would like to prevent an application for asking (repeatedly) for administrator privileges.

Specifically, I use the MacOS version of WhatsApp (on 10.14). Owing in part to the recent controversy about their changed EU EULA acceptance terms (which I have not agreed to) and a change they made that removed a very helpful 'right click' 'copy image' function, I am happy with my version of the client, and don't want to upgrade it. I've got it installed in `/Applications/`, owned by `root` and without write permissions to other groups (i.e. `drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel`).

Periodically, it asks to update using one of MacOS's own dialogue boxes. I'd like to avoid having to click 'cancel' a lot. Can I indicate this preference to MacOS, and get it to automatically deny such requests for this specific application?

[image: An example of the GUI requesting privs]

Comment: Isn't this rather a question about "how can I prevent WhatsApp on Mac from auto-updating"?

Comment: @nohillside That's my specific use case -- but in general, no: this dialogue box appears elsewhere (as it's provided by the OS) and one can imagine other questioners wanting to do the same thing for totally different reasons.

Comment: I understand that. Only problem is that there is no such mechanism in macOS. There might be ways to prevent WhatsApp from trying to auto-update though.

Comment: If you don't agree to the current EULA surely you should stop using WhatsApp and uninstall.  I am sure the EULA refers to the service and not just the specific client version.